# Python and gdal 1.10 gives numpy.core.multiarray failed to import on OSX

Tags: macos, gdal, qgis

I recently upgraded QGIS to 2.0 using Kyngchaos packages only to discover that my kriging scipts which I run in iPython then threw up the following error:

numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

It seems that the pathname variable assigned by SWIG is incompatible with iPython. I hate path management, it seems to be the single greatest cause of errors on UNIX machines.

Anyway, a rather clumsy fix to this is to copy the Python/2.7/site-packages from from version 1.9 of gdal to version 1.10 (renaming the original 1.10 directory to something appropriately rude) This works for iPython at least and QGIS seems to function still.
Can somebody suggest a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have QGIS 2.0 and GDAL 1.10 installed from Kyngchaos pre-compiled distributions, and was also having this error.

It seems it was expecting a newer version of numpy (I was running 1.6), and I'm assuming QGIS/GDAL expect the lib to be in a certain path, since it's a pre-compiled version. So, for me, installing the numpy package also available from [Kyngchaos,](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python) which is version 1.7.1, solved the problem.

Comment: I have found quite a nice solution to a lot of problems involving Python versions, paths etc. Anaconda gives you a nicely partitioned installation of Python 2.7 plus most of the useful scientific packages (and more) that you might need.The only problem I found was that the gdal package was faulty but you can simply add a pth file in the Anaconda installation pointing to the KyngChaos gdal bundle.

Comment: And which version of python does your qgis run over?

Comment: 2.7 but you can get anaconda for 3.x as well

Comment: Well, hold on. My girlfriend ran this set up on her work desktop just fine for a clean install of Mavericks, then tried the same thing on her MBP, eventually even copying the .bash_profile and *.pth file from her desktop, but QGIS complained that it couldn't find Matplotlib despite python finding it just fine. I HATE path management in UNIX.